# Is there a way to convert from timezone format (America/Chicago) to UTC (-0500) in C# .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm being provided a set of timezone names and need to use them as UTC offsets. Is there a way to make this conversion to get the current UTC offset (including appropriate DST shift)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=net-5.0

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a one way conversion; a city and a time zone offset are only loosely related

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [`TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getutcoffset) method is designed to accomplish.

```
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Chicago");
TimeSpan offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(utcNow);
```

The above will work if you are running .NET on Linux or Mac OSX, and in the future (starting with .NET 6) will work on Windows.

If you are running .NET on Windows today, you can use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter) library which will internally convert the IANA time zone ID to a Windows time zone ID when getting a `TimeZoneInfo` object.

```
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo tz = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Chicago");
TimeSpan offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(utcNow);
```